# Spring JSON url pattern not acceptable

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

Im developing web application using springMVC 3.2.6 and Hibernate 3.3.1

when I mapped a spring URL pattern as `*.htm`
and request a URL is `getname.htm` the method is working fine as checked in debug mode and `system.out.println` but the JSON is not generated and the output shows as

> The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().

When I mapped a spring URL pattern as `/rest/` and request the url is `/rest/getname` it gives perfect JSON output:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getname", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<String> getNameInJSON() {            

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the "Accept" header in your browser debugger and play with produces property.

see [Producible Media Types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces)